# Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set

Tags: java, windows, activemq-artemis

My OS is Windows 10. I had an error when starting the `.\artemis` in the Windows PowerShell. It said:

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
```

I already setting the JAVA_HOME's path at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin`. This is the result for `echo %JAVA_HOME%`:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\
```

I tried to test the `mvn -v`:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 19.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

(it should not be shown if the JAVA_HOME is not set tho)

I tried the `java -version`:

```
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The `javac -version`:

```
javac 19.0.1
```

Can someone explain how to fix it?

I forgot to mention it
when I use git bash to run `./artemis` the result is

`./artemis: line 93: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19;/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Nothing `*_HOME` should have a bin directory in the path. It's the *installation* directory

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm using apache-artemis-2.26.0

oh yeah when I use git bash to start `./artemis` this is the result

`./artemis: line 93: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19;/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and set Java SDK 11 as JAVA_HOME.
Most applications will not work with SDK 18 or higher.

Artemis notes:

> Note on Java versions: The old v17.0.1 version of the Artemis software required Java version 1.8 to run. All recent releases from v18.0.0 onwards require a minimum of Java 9 and ideally Java 11. This must be installed first.

Extracted from http://sanger-pathogens.github.io/Artemis/

Comment: I've tried it and it works, thank you

Comment: There is no version "17.0.1" of ActiveMQ Artemis. The documentation you cited is for a _completely_ different project related to "genome browsing and annotation."

Comment: @JustinBertram There is a huge large lot of things with this name (Artemis). I couldn't guess haha. But this problem with Java is very universal.

Comment: @RenatoAraújo, the problem with your answer is that ActiveMQ Artemis _does work_ with Java 19. The problem is almost certainly with the script used to start the broker on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the short name? It’s been some time since I used Windows but
if I recall correctly I used to use PROGRA~1 instead of "Program files".